# eclipse antsvn export task fails

Tags: svn, ant, svnkit, svnant

I’m creating the following build file, in order to retrieve my project from the SVN repository:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="svn-test_2" default="checkoutThis" basedir=".">
    <property file="build.svn.properties" />
    <taskdef name="svn" classname="org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask" />
    <target name="checkoutThis">
        <svn javahl="false" svnkit="true" username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}">
            <export srcurl="${svn.repository.url}" destPath="${svnant.destination.url}" force='true'/>
        </svn>
    </target>
</project>
```

I’m using SvnAnt version 1.2, Subversion server 1.6 and Subclipse 1.6.

The output is an error:

```
checkoutThis:
    [svn] <Export> started ...
    [svn] svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/repos/wiam11g/!svn/vcc/default) 
    [svn] svn: REPORT request failed on '/repos/wiam11g/!svn/vcc/default'
    [svn] svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/repos/wiam11g/!svn/vcc/default) 
    [svn] svn: REPORT request failed on '/repos/wiam11g/!svn/vcc/default'
    [svn] <Export> failed !
BUILD FAILED
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure your svn url is correct? Why such an old version of svnant?

Comment: The url is the right one. I have tried with the last version of svnant that I found here: http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html and I am getting the same error message

Comment: Try setting `javahl="true"` on the `<svn>` task

Comment: svnkit.http.methods=Basic fixed the problem